# Triple-loop Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, loops, each

I know the idea of a triple loop brings fear to the minds of some, but I have a code with the following structure:

```
paragraph.split(/(\.|\?|\!)[\s\Z]/).each do |sentence|
    myArrayOfFiles.each_with_index { |ma,j|
        ma.each_with_index { |word,i|
            sentence.gsub!(...)
        }
    }
end
```

The two outer loops run as expected, but for some reason, the inner loop runs over the first `sentence` only. Do you know why this is? How can I make the inner loop run over all `sentence`s too?

I am running on Ruby 1.8.7, and have tried the same code above using just the `each` loop and got the same results. Any ideas?

EDIT:

`myArrayOfFiles` is an array filled by:

```
AFile = File.open("A.txt")
BFile = File.open("B.txt")
myArrayOfFiles << [Afile,BFile]
myArrayOfFiles.flatten!
```

Comment: where is `sentence` being used?

Comment: What is the "some stuff"? What do the elements of `myArrayOfFiles` look like?

Comment: `sentence` is used in the inner loop.

Comment: I made an edit which shows what `myArrayOfFiles` consists of. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I edited the "some stuff" also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that `myArrayOfFiles` contains File instances. When you iterate through one of your Files with `ma.each_with_index`, it will go through the file line by line and stop at EOF. Then, you try to iterate again with the next `sentence` but the File is already at EOF so `ma.each_with_index` has nothing to iterate over and nothing interesting happens. You need to call [`rewind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-rewind) to move the Files back to the beginning before you try to `each_with_index` them again:

```
paragraph.split(/(\.|\?|\!)[\s\Z]/).each do |sentence|
  myArrayOfFiles.each_with_index do |ma, j|
    ma.rewind # <------------------------- You need this
    ma.each_with_index do |word, i|
      sentence.gsub!(...)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Works great! So if I understand correctly, this logic holds for any kind of loop. Thanks!

Comment: @zanbri: Right, your loops weren't the problem, the Files were.